# debug XE6 Mac applications in Xcode

Tags: xcode, delphi, delphi-xe6

How do I debug Delphi XE6 OS X applications in Xcode? I can attach to the running process on the Mac but there is no debug information, to do this I have to have some other Xcode project open. If I have no project open in Xcode then debug/attach to process is greyed out.

I imagine I have to tell Xcode where the Debug info is somehow? Note the target is OS X not iOS.

xcode 6.4, OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, Delphi XE6

(why would I want to do this? I have some native NSViews created in the app and there are some z-order problems. I want to use the Xcode debug view hierarchy tools to see whats going on)

Update 1: By following the instructions here http://therobotsbrain.blogspot.com.au/2010/01/debugging-non-xcode-code-in-xcode.html I can run my application from Xcode but no debug information. So I have to set the debug info somewhere in Xcode.Maybe this is just an Xcode problem - added the Xcode tag hopefully some Xcode wiz can show me the way)

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you'll have any success here. Emba surely use their own proprietary debug info. Trace debugging is probably what you need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes that has been the conclusion I came to. The debug info delphi produces just isn't recognised by XCode. Even tried a disassembler (hopper) and it can't do anything with the debug info, just an unrecognised format. Oh well, back to printing out to the logs